# Read a text file through a batch script

Tags: batch-file

I have a notepad file as follows:

> EID: id
>
> Password: password

I want to read the eid values and the password values and paste it into a variable through a batch script. how do i go about this?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP just ask : please write me the code to do that and do not show any effort in finding the solution himself.

Comment: The "notepad file" term have no sense. The created "text file" have no relation with notepad...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## New answer (no temp file)

---

```bat
@echo off
for /f "delims=: tokens=1*" %%G in (a.txt) do set %%G=%%H
set eid=%eid:~1%& set password=%password:~1%
pause
```

Explanation:

```
+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+  
|Explanation                                                 |Result (EID)       |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|Line 2: Use a for loop to extract the string after :        |" ThisIsYourEidNow"|
+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
|Line 3: Use variable substring to remove the leading space  |"ThisIsYourEidNow" |
+------------------------------------------------------------+-------------------+
```

## Old answer (uses temp file) ↴

---

```bat
@echo off
for /f "tokens=2* delims=: " %%p in (textfile.txt) do echo %%p >> tmp.txt
(
set /p "line1="
set /p "line2="
) <tmp.txt
del /f /s /q tmp.txt
pause
```

The script does:

- Only reads the part after `:`( SE is bad at displaying spaces ) and store them into a temp file
- Read each line of the temp file and store them into the variables
- Delete the temp file
- Pause

Comment: Why are you using **`:~3`** it makes little sense. If you're going to manipulate the variable then you'd remove everything up to and including the first space!

Comment: @compo that's why I changed it. (note: when I test it I used string `a: eid` and I used *`:~3`*

Comment: As compo said, it's simpler to remove all up to the first `: ` with `set "line1=%line1:*: =%"`

Comment: @jeb will edit my answer

Answer (score 1):

This alternative doesn't make and delete an additional file.

```bat
@Echo Off
For /F "UseBackQ Tokens=1* Delims=:" %%A In ("notepad.txt") Do Call :Sub %%A %%B
Set _
Timeout -1
Exit/B

:Sub
Set "_%1=%2"
```

Comment: Nice script! However, this will display unneeded info when unneeded variables if there are other variables starting with _

Comment: The OP didn't ask for the display of the variables, that was added just to show that it had worked. They can reference them by their names directly, `%_EID%` & `%_Password%` in their working script.